# How to host an API on Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I have scourged through the internet and through MSDN sites to find out a simple example to host an API on Azure mobile apps.  I partially understand what are Controllers, but I do not know how to map the url addresses to the controller.

For example, if my baseUrl is `http://{my_site_address}/{my_site_name}` and I want to add an API named `get_next_post`, how do I map this API to the controller such that `baseUrl/get_next_post` calls the Post or Get method of that controller.

Once I know this, I can write more such API's and map them to controllers similarly.

Is there a concrete documentation on this? The Azure MSDN pages keep talking about offline data sync, push notifications etc but they don't talk about how to simply host an API.

Answer (score 1):

I found a really informative article here [Custom HTTP Endpoints](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/custom/). I am surprised that none of the Azure documentation pages and videos mentioned that the custom Controller name specifies the `baseUrl/api/{api_name}`, as mentioned in the article.